# How to optimize transition to update ui with uicollectionview or uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimationtransition

this is my very first question. My Eng is not good so i hope i can make my question clearly as possible.

My app use an UICollectionView to display photos download from my remote server. I set a light gray image for it as place holder and when the photo finished download i set it with transition method:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:cellNeedReload.photo duration:0.3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
    cellNeedReload.photo.image = downloader.photo.image;
} completion:nil];
```

In my code above, i wrote it in a completionBlock nsoperation. It works perfect but not synchronized and my grid have some lags when scrolling with many photos in animations. How to optimize it ?

I see some apps like Pinterest have very smooth grid in transition.

Comment: Please refer this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745630/uicollectionview-scrolling-is-slow

Comment: Thanks but it not help me. I ask for optimize transition, not how to  use thread to render images in grid :)